# Why does this cause a StackOverFlow error?

Tags: c#, .net

This is causing a StackOverFlow error and I have an idea why, but I would like a little more detail on why and is my solution for it the way it should be handled.  Ok, first things first, the following code causes a StackOverFlow error when I try to assign a value to the property:

```
private List<Albums> albums
{
    get
    {
        if (Session["albums"] != null)
            return (List<Albums>)Session["albums"];
        else
            return AlbumCollection.GetAlbums();
    }
    set
    {
    albums = value;
    Session["albums"] = albums;
    }
}
```

To resolve the above, I changed the name of the property and added another variable to hold the value of the property which resolved the StackOverFlow issue:

```
private List<Albums> albums = null;
private List<Albums> Albums
{
    get
    {
        if (Session["albums"] != null)
            return (List<Albums>)Session["albums"];
        else
            return AlbumCollection.GetAlbums();
    }
    set
    {
    albums = value;
    Session["albums"] = albums;
    }
}
```

Also, am I doing the setter correct, assigning the value and then assigning the Session["albums"] the value in albums?  Could I have just done,  Session["albums"] = value instead?

Comment: After some brisk searching, this should help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929141/why-does-this-cause-a-stackoverflow-error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were reassigning to the property itself.

In your case, you are only using the Session.

So this should be fine

```
private List<Albums> albums
{
    get
    {
        if (Session["albums"] == null)
            Session["albums"] = AlbumCollection.GetAlbums();
        return (List<Albums>)Session["albums"];
    }
    set
    {
        Session["albums"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, I was thinking I could do that, but I was afraid I would do it wrong if I didn't do albums = value first. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Because in your setter, you are calling ... the *setter*, which goes to the setter, and calls ... the ***setter*** ... and ...

```
 set
 {    
    albums = value;       // < --- This line calls itself again.. 
    Session["albums"] = albums;
 }
```

What you need to do is just use the the Session["albums"] as the persistent storage for the value...  You don't need a private field - that's just creating a redundant copy of the value.  Eliminate it entirely, and just put...

```
private List<Albums> Albums
{    
    get    
    {        
         if (Session["albums"] != null)
              return (List<Albums>) Session["albums"];        
         else            
            return (Session["albums"] = AlbumCollection.GetAlbums());    
    }    
    set    
    {    
        Session["albums"] = value;    
    }
}
```

In certain scenarios where you do not have a persistent store, it's perfectly acceptable for a public property to have just a private member backing field.

For more info on C# properties in general, check out the [MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: So, if I just had Session["albums"] = value, it would be fine?

Comment: @Xaisoft: Yes, it's all you need.

Comment: @Xaisoft: that's one way of doing it;  However, if the Albums property is accessed a couple times during the page processing it's much better to cache the deserialized results into a private member.

Comment: Ok, a little confused, should I do Session["albums"] = value or Session["albums"] = albums or is it the same.

Comment: @Chris, are you referring to the way I am actually doing it by declaring the private variable albums in my second attempt?  This also brings up another question, how does creating  another variable cache the results?  I am not to clear on this?

Comment: @Wim, not at all, But I don;t see them.. Perhaps I was editing at the same time and overwrote yr changes ? If so, please add again...

Comment: Yes - indeed, a case of 'last-write-wins' concurrency in action. ;-)

Comment: @Xaisoft,  Definitely need "Session["albums"] = value"  the other was my bad for copy paste from yr code...

Comment: Charles, you said I don't need the private field because it is redundant, but what about the comment that Chris Lively made about if I have a private field, it will cache the results.

Comment: He's talking about the difference in read performance accssing a session variable vs. accessing a variable in a method's stack frame. It used to be (some time ago - old classic ASP) that variables or data stored in Session state were substantially more difficult and/or prone to errors than other variables. I don;t believe this is stil the case with ASP.Net, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ah ok, so by using a private variable to hold the results of the property, I am accessing the the variable from the stack, but if I don't use a private variable, I am accessing it directly from the session which in the past, was possibly slower, do I have that correct?

Comment: Yes, and, again, as I mentioned, Generally, with standard ASP.Net session, I don't believe there is any real performance issue with in ASP.Net.  As I recall, it might be a bit slower if you elect to store session in a database, or on a shared server, (which you might do if your Web Server is in a farm and you wish to share session state among all the members in the farm)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with this line:

```
albums = value;
```

You are recursively setting the property to `value` which will call the setter again and again, until it stackoverflows. There's no point in that line of code. Just get rid of it.

I guess there's a false misconception that a property needs to be bound to a field or something. It's not. A property, by itself, is just a couple unrelated methods, that are not required to have any specific relation to each other or to a field. When you retrieve the property value, you just call its `get` method and use the return value and when you set its value, you call its `set` method with the appropriate `value` argument. You don't need to somehow "change" the property value in setter. The semantics are automatically enforced as you are changing the value that `get` is going to return so the next time you call get, it will return `Session["..."]` which you have already changed.

Answer (score 3):

This line is causing your issue, because it winds up calling your getter recursively in an infinite loop:

```
albums = value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your setter is calling itself recursively in the first example. Your second fixes this.

Yes, you could have done.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, in the first example you are recursively calling the album setter infinite times, hence the stack overflow.  (C# Properties and methods should always start with an uppercase letter btw).

In the second example you could simply use:

```
Session["albums"] = value;
```

if you wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the issue is when ever you use "albums" in the first code block you are referring to this setter/getter.  Thus when you do `albums = value` in the setter you are recursively calling the setter again.

Internally, the compiler converts accessors to functions, and it may help you to see your error by doing this yourself:

```
private List<Albums> albums
{
    set
    {
    albums = value;
    Session["albums"] = albums;
    }
}
```

When compiled, becomes:

```
private void set_albums(List<Albums> value)
{
    set_albums(value);
    Session["albums"] = albums;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a common mistake to call Session["Albums"] twice. Session indexing is a relatively expensive operation involving a dictionary lookup.

```
private List<Albums> Albums {    
get
{        
     object stored = Session["albums"];
     if (stored != null)
          return (List<Albums>) stored;
     else
     {      
        var newValue = AlbumCollection.GetAlbums();
        Albums = newValue;
        return newValue;
     }
}    
set    
{    
    Session["albums"] = value;
}}
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, instead of accessing session in the if statement and when I return the List of albums, store it in an object first and check the object?  Correct?